# Select element based on another elements attribute

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I have an XML document in the following format:

```
<CollectionMappingData>
  <ContentTypes>
    <ContentType ContentTypeName="Content Type Name" SomeAttr="ValueINeed" />
  </ContentTypes>
  <CollectionGroup CollectionName="collection_name" ContentTypeName="Content Type Name"/>
  <CollectionGroup CollectionName="collection_name2" ContentTypeName="Content Type Name 2"/>
  <CollectionGroup CollectionName="collection_name3" ContentTypeName="Content Type Name 3"/>
</CollectionMappingData>
```

Given a Collection name, I'm searching for a `CollectionName` within a `<CollectionGroup />`, then I am trying to find a `<ContentType />` based on the `CollectionName`.  Here is my JS so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#inputForm").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var collectionName = $('#collectionName').val(); // User supplied collection name

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ContentTypeMapData.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    findCollectionGroup(xml, collectionName);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });

    function findCollectionGroup(xml, collectionName) {
        var output = '';
        var collectionGroup = $(xml).find('CollectionGroup[CollectionName=' + collectionName + ']');
        var contentType = $(xml).find('ContentType[ContentTypeName=' + $(collectionGroup).attr('ContentTypeName') + ']');

        output += contentType.attr("SomeAttr");

        $("#xmlDump").append(output);
    }
```

It doesn't appear to be finding the `<ContentType />` as I expected, even though it does exist within the XML.  I think I'm missing something fundamental here about how the language works.

Comment: You have two double quotes at the end of the contentType assignment: + '""]'

Comment: Good catch.  Same results, unfortunately.

Comment: It turns out ron tornambe was right.  It was my double quotes.  I just never had them match up properly which seemed to be the root of all my problems.  This fixed it:

    var contentType = $(xml).find('ContentType[ContentTypeName="' + $(collectionGroup).attr("ContentTypeName") + '"]')

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out ron tornambe was right. It was my double quotes. I just never had them match up properly which seemed to be the root of all my problems. This fixed it:

```
var contentType = $(xml).find('ContentType[ContentTypeName="' + $(collectionGroup).attr("ContentTypeName") + '"]')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on the syntax and I can't test it at the moment but you're probably looking for something like this:

findCollectionGroup function:

```
function findCollectionGroup(xml, collectionName) {
        var output = '';
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        $cg = $xml.find("CollectionGroup").attr("CollectionName",collectionName);
        $ct = $xml.find("ContentType").attr("ContentTypeName").each(function() {
            if($(this) == $cg)
                $("#xmlDump").append($(this));
        })
 }
```